# Datagrid not showing data even though its boudn

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a problem with my MVVM Light implementation where I have my WPF Toolkit DataGrid and Data context bound to the correct object but no data is showing up. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

> MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private C.Wsi.ClientSession privateSession;

    private ObservableCollection<CashAccount> _cashaccounts;

    public ObservableCollection<CashAccount> CashAccounts
    {
        get { return _cashaccounts; }
        set
        {
            if (_cashaccounts.Equals(value))
            {
                return;
            }
            _cashaccounts = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CashAccounts");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        }
        else
        {

            _cashaccounts = new ObservableCollection<CashAccount>();

             // Subscribe to CollectionChanged event
          _cashaccounts.CollectionChanged += OnCashAccountListChanged;

            logger.Info("-----  Start   -----");

            // Code runs "for real"
            Cs.Helper.Session session = new Session();
            privateSession = session.getSession();
            logger.Info("Private Session: " + privateSession.GetHashCode());
            logger.Info("...Connected.....");

            Cs.Helper.ResultSet results = new ResultSet();

            PositionBean[] pos = results.getPositions(privateSession);
            logger.Info("Positions returned: " + pos.Length);

            SecurityBean[] secs = results.getSecurities(privateSession);
            logger.Info("Securities returned: " + secs.Length);

            ArrayBuilder ab = new ArrayBuilder(pos, secs);
            CashAccount c = new CashAccount();
            c.qtySod = 100.00;
            c.name = "Hi";
            c.account = "Acct1";
            c.cashAmount = 67.00;
            _cashaccounts.Add(c);
            RaisePropertyChanged("CashAccounts");
            //this._cashaccounts=ab.joinPositionSecurities();
        }
    }
     void OnCashAccountListChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {

      }


    ////public override void Cleanup()
    ////{
    ////    // Clean up if needed

    ////    base.Cleanup();
    ////}
}
```

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CreditSuisse.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CreditSuisse.Helper"
    xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="301"
    Width="520"
    Title="Credit Suisse - Custodial Cash Application"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />

        <!-- DataGrid Background -->
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BlueLightGradientBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFEAF3FF"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.654" Color="#FFC0DEFF"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFC0D9FB"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <!-- DatGrid style -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueLightGradientBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFA6CCF2" />
            <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#FDFFD0" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFD3D0" />
            <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
        </Style>

        <!-- Enable rows as drop targets -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<dg:DataGrid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding CashAccounts}">
          Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="False">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding account}" Header="Account Code" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Security Name" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cashAmount}" Header="Quantity Start of Day" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding price}" Header="Cash Delta (Price Delta)" />
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Get" Visibility="{Binding cashChanged, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Background="Red" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `DataContext="{Binding Path=Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"` in your Window and after `DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}"` in the Datagrid, WPF tries to bind to a `property named MainViewModel` on your `MainViewModel` class which will fail. You can confirm this by looking for the binding error in the Output window in VS.
Just remove  `DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}"` from the `DataGrid` and it should work.

EDIT:
There is an extra closing > at the end of the first line in your XAML:

```
<dg:DataGrid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding CashAccounts}">
          Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="False">
```

It should be:

```
<dg:DataGrid DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding CashAccounts}"
          Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Note: `False` is not a valid value for `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` it supports `Auto, Disabled, Hidden, Visible`

But I don't know why WPF throws `Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead` for your original XAML instead of some more meaningful error.

Comment: I originally did this because that is seems to work for MVVM Light. However, when you do this you get the following:{"Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."}, This is why I added it. When I use Snoop and use the previous implementation, I can see that my observable collection is bound. Any thoughts?

Comment: I could repro your error, and I've updated my answer with my findings.